# Is there a "watch window" like GDB function?

Tags: gdb

In `gdb`, when it hits a breakpoint, I need to manually investigate the variable values, one by one, with `print` or `print/x` functions.

Is there any easier way to list all selected variable's values whenever it hits a breakpoint, commonly known as a "watch window" of a GUI debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands can be executed on breakpoints.

From docs:

```
break foo
commands
printf "x is %d\n",x
end
```

Or add commands to some existing breakpoint (breakpoint number 3 in this case):

```
commands 3
print x
print y
end
```

Or make a command that adds prints to a breakpoint:

```
define addwatch
commands $arg0
print x
print y
end
end
```

Then use:

```
addwatch 3
```

Or make a command that sets a breakpoint and adds prints to it.

Scripts can be stored in `.gdbinit`, so they'll load automatically. The language is either this GDB syntax or Python.

P.S. Some people do tracing with this by adding `continue` at the end of the command list: that way the variables are printed, but the application doesn't stop on the breakpoint.